# how to pull the source code from a facebook app in a java application

Tags: java, facebook

Hi I've set up a java app. and I can connect and such and my facebook session validates.

I can get the person signed in id and the info etc. but the app that I am using I cant get to the content.

I've tried it with my own id and using it but facebook seems to spit back a whole lot of garbage that I am assuming that its thinking that I am some kind of bot or spider... as the term spider is referenced a couple times in that garbage.

my code is as follows

```
public class m extends WebPage {

public m() {

    FaceBookSession session = (FaceBookSession) getSession();


        String contents = "";

    System.err.println("*****************************************************************");
    System.err.println("id ==================" + session.getId());
    System.err.println("name ==================" + session.getUserName());

    try {
        URL aURL = new URL("http://apps.facebook.com/<___>/profile.php?snuid=<__>");
        URLConnection aURLc = aURL.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(aURLc.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            contents = contents + " <br> " + inputLine;
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }

        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.add(new Label("username", session.getId()));
    this.add(new Label("user", session.getUserName()));
    this.add(new Label("id", contents));

    System.err.println("*****************************************************************");
```

Is there something that I can do? I've tried this with myself and my account and I am logged into facebook and using the app in question. but when I run this program I cant gain access to the application im usings page to pull the content.

I just want to be able to access all my applications that I am using and display their contents/page all together on one single page.

[EDIT] - I'm pretty sure the problem is to do with that the program isn't emulating a browser or something like that, cookies etc. that the program doesnt pass the info needed or sommething. maybe there is a way to "log in" via a java program first then proceed to the wanted page.

Cheers for any help

Comment: Are you sure it is not spitting zipped (compressed) information? Can you post some of the garbage?

Comment: i'm pretty sure i've figured the problem. being that the app isn't able to emulate the browser and hence any cookies etc that the app needs to load isn't loading. or the fact that when i hit the url of the site that any extra info that is usually passed between facebook and the app is not happening. it's not compressed or anything, i'm pretty sure its the info of accessing facebook without being "logged in", so its the source code of that page

Comment: Right. If that's your problem you should check to use HttpClient from apache, it will manage cookies for you.

Comment: Hi David. Did you really figured out the problem? Can you please then close this question? Thx

Comment: wow this was a long time ago, if i knew how to close a question then sure i would....